# CSS - Why can't I vertical align this image in this div?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm attempting to use the line-height method to v-align an image within a div.

I do not understand why it's not working.

This method has been gone over multiple times on StackOverflow.

If you simply replace the img with text, the text v-aligns without problem.

```
<div class="image_wrapper">
    <img src="http://requestaweb.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/css.png">
</div>

.image_wrapper {
    height: 400px;
    line-height: 400px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    height: 200px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Nikzilla/q3Lu8nrm/1/

Comment: Its vertically aligned for me. I'm using firefox.

Comment: Probably better to not post a link to a collaborative fiddle next time

Comment: How the hell do I post the old school shares? All I see is the collaborate button.

Comment: Click save, copy and paste the url in the address bar. Why would you need a button for that?

Comment: the url just shows /#

Comment: Did you save? I just made a new one and save gives me an actual link.

Comment: @RickCalder Save button only seems to show up if you're signed in. Not sure when that changed.

Comment: So it does... that's a terrible change. =/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically align an image inside div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273338/how-to-vertically-align-an-image-inside-div)

Comment: @RickCalder Just to follow up on the jsFiddle bit; the reason for no anonymous fiddles was apparently to recover from a DDOS attack. They've been re-enabled: https://twitter.com/jsfiddle/status/497083687406956544 (just FYI).

Answer (score 2):

Change your css like this

```
.image_wrapper {
    height: 400px;
    line-height: 400px;

    background-color: gray;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

This works.. I've tried..

Comment: Works in fiddle but not on my page, sigh

Answer (score 0):

Image need to know how to align itself also add a more strict CSS rule instead of adding a generic rule for img tag.

```
.image_wrapper {
height: 400px;
line-height: 400px;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color: gray;
text-align: center;
}

.image_wrapper img {
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Cheers !!